# How can I filter for string values in a mixed datatype object in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a Pandas Dataframe like:(whose value_counts are shown below)

```
1                      246804
2                      135272
5                        8983
8                        3459
4                        3177
6                        1278
9                         522
D                         314
E                          91
0                          29
F                          20    
Name: Admission_Source_Code, dtype: int64
```

As you can see it contains both integers and letters. I'm having to write a function where I would have to filter and search for the lettered values.

I was initially importing this dataset using pd.read_excel, but after having read multiple bug reports, it seems that read_excel doesnt have option to explicitly read a column as a string.

So I tried reading using pd.read_csv which has the dtype option. Initially this column was being stored as float64 by default, now even though I have tried to run

```
Df_name['Admission_Source_Code'] = Df_name['Admission_Source_Code'].astype(int).astype('str')
```

I'm unable to format it as a string column.

Hence, when I filter for

```
Accepted[Accepted['Admission_Source_Code']==1]
```

it works, but

```
Accepted[Accepted['Admission_Source_Code']=='E']
```

still returns no results. When i try and say str(column_name) in the mask, it says invalid literal.
Can someone please help me on how would i go about either changing the dtype or how to filter for lettered values?

Thanks.

P.S. even formatting as object doesnt help

Comment: Have you tried a list comprehesion? for example: `Df_name['Admission_Source_Code'] = [str(i) for i in Df_name['Admission_Source_Code']]` ***?***

Comment: @estebanpdl : The list comprehension seemed to have worked partially only. I wanted to upload an image, so you can see what happened in the answer I posted. I'm unable to understand why it is happening. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to filter your `value_counts` series using `.loc[]` indexer, filtering (indexing) by strings

Demo:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
                        Count
Admission_Source_Code
1                      246804
2                      135272
5                        8983
8                        3459
4                        3177
6                        1278
9                         522
D                         314
E                          91
0                          29
F                          20

In [28]: df.index.dtype
Out[28]: dtype('O')

In [29]: df.loc['2']
Out[29]:
Count    135272
Name: 2, dtype: int64

In [30]: df.loc[['2','E','5','D']]
Out[30]:
                        Count
Admission_Source_Code
2                      135272
E                          91
5                        8983
D                         314
```

List index values:

```
In [36]: df.index.values
Out[36]: array(['1', '2', '5', '8', '4', '6', '9', 'D', 'E', '0', 'F'], dtype=object)
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: The ix or loc method will definitely work if I was filtering the value_counts series. Thanks for that. But while writing my function, I'm trying to filter the dataframe itself. Here is what happened when I tried to do the list comprehension for that column. I'm sorry but I had to upload that output as an image, and that has been posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests using your example and filters works well, for example:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('Yourfile.csv')
df['Admission_Source_Code'].value_counts()

1                      246804
2                      135272
5                        8983
8                        3459
4                        3177
6                        1278
9                         522
D                         314
E                          91
0                          29
F                          20    
Name: Admission_Source_Code, dtype: int64
```

If I try:

```
print (df[(df['Admission_Source_Code']==1)])
```

I got:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Admission_Source_Code]
Index: []
```

However with a `list comprehesion`

```
df['Admission_Source_Code'] = [str(i) for i in df['Admission_Source_Code']]
```

Using a data example:

[image]

If problems persist, have you considered clean items from csv columns? *(i.e. a whitespace)*.

For example using the same `list comprehesion` and `strip()`:

```
df['Admission_Source_Code'] = [str(i.strip()) for i in df['Admission_Source_Code']]
```